# How to create associations between models in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, node-sqlite3

I am creating a game using node.js and I would like to save data in a database (sqlite3) using sequelize.js.

I have 2 models right now: `User` and `Clan`.

I want them to have such relationships:

- A `User` can have a `Clan` as `clan`
- A `Clan` can have a `User` as `owner`
- A `Clan` can have many `User` as `members`, `owner` included

In other words, `<User>.clan` should be an instance of a `Clan`, `<Clan>.owner` should be an instance of a `User`, and `<Clan>.members` should be an array of `User` instances.

Currently while trying to setup such relationships, I get cyclic dependency errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/base.js%7EAssociation.html), you should use `constraints: false` on your models declaration (only on Clan -> Owner relationship in your case) to avoid cyclic dependency errors.